# Flutter space evenly scrollable layout

Tags: flutter, layout, scroll, singlechildscrollview

I have following design:

[image]

Code:

```
body: Container(
  color: Colors.green,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: const Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        // TEXT
        // TEXT
        // IMAGE
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

It is fine, when the device is smaller, the column is scrollable:

[image]

However, when the device is bigger, I would like to achieve following:

[image]

Explanation: all three elements are spaced evenly in the layout. First is on the top, last is on the bottom. If there is enough space, there are spaces between the elements. However, if there is no space, the column would become scrollable. Can somebody advise how to solve this?

I have tried `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,`, but that does not work. Even wrapping the parent container with `Expanded` does not work either. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you want the first and third rectangles to be the same height?

Comment: Ah nevermind, you want them have natural height, just the space between them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually use something from the example of [`SingleChildScrollView` docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html):

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 200),
          Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 200),
          Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 200),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

What you are doing here is making the `Column` have a minimum constraint equal to the available height (the space you have). Thanks to this, there's a free space available in the `Column` which is used for the `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`. If the column contents won't fit within that space, the max height constraint is still infinite, so it will nicely expand and the `SingleChildScrollView` will make the contents scrollable.

Just be sure to not use this pattern for longer or more complex (in terms of the widget tree) views, as the `SingleChildScrollView` lays out the whole child widget tree which for more complex trees may get expensive and your frame time may suffer.